# i'm trying a windowed word count application streams, in consumer console i have some unreadable characters alongwith count

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, dsl, confluent-platform

[image: The output on consumer console screenshot]

The application (.java) file is as given below;

```
public class WordCountFinal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringSerializer stringSerializer = new StringSerializer();
        StringDeserializer stringDeserializer = new StringDeserializer();
        TimeWindowedSerializer<String> windowedSerializer = new TimeWindowedSerializer<>(stringSerializer);
        TimeWindowedDeserializer<String> windowedDeserializer = new TimeWindowedDeserializer<>(stringDeserializer);
        Serde<Windowed<String>> windowedSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(windowedSerializer, windowedDeserializer);


        Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "rogue");
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "ssc-vm-r.com:9092, ssc-vmr:9092, ssc-vm:9092");
        streamsConfiguration.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.Long().getClass());

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<String, String> wordcountinput = builder.stream("TextLinesTopic", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

        KGroupedStream<String, String> groupedStream = wordcountinput
                .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+")))
                .map((key, word) -> new KeyValue<>(word, word))
                .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

        KTable<Windowed<String>, Long> aggregatedStream = groupedStream
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(2)))
                .count();

        aggregatedStream.toStream().to("tuesdaystopic", Produced.with(windowedSerde, Serdes.Long()));

        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamsConfiguration);
        streams.start();

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));

    }

}
```

input to producer console is sentences or words. output should be like similar wordcount app, but after 2 minutes, suppose till now i have word count for 'qwerty' as 5. and after two mins i enter again qwerty in producer console, i should get outputted count as 1.

qwerty 3

qwerty 4

qwerty 5

abcd 1

after 2 mins and entering qwerty in prod. console

qwerty  1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the type of the key of the result is `Windowed<String>` -- that's also why you use a `TimeWindowedSerializer` when writing the result stream to a topic via `to()` (you don't use a `StringSerializer`).

When you read the data with the console consumer, you specify `StringDeserializer` for the key though, however, the bytes in the key is not of type `String` and thus you get those unreadable characters and the types don't match.

You can either specify a different deserializer (ie, `TimeWindowedDeserializer` when using the console consumer, or you modify the key to type `String` before writing the result into the output topic. For example you could use:

```java
aggregatedStream.toStream()
    // `k` is of type Windowed<String>
    // you can get the plain String key via `key()`
    .selectKey((k,v) -> k.key())
    .to(....)
```

Comment: Thank you Matthias! the conversion part worked. but for consumer console, timewindoweddeserializer should work actually; but doesn't. But thanks anyways! Helped a lot.

Comment: How did you try to use `TimeWindowedDeserializer` and why did it not work for you?

Comment: i used this on consumer console ./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092     --topic tuesdaystopic     --from-beginning     --formatter kafka.tools.DefaultMessageFormatter     --property print.key=true     --property print.value=true     --property key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TimeWindowedDesrializer     --property value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDeserializer

Comment: for other variations it couldn't find the class. i guess i'm going wrong somewhere. please correct me.

Comment: And what was the problem with the command? Did it fail? Or what did it print?

Comment: no it didn't print, it gave error saying that class exception not found.... the org.apache.kafka......

Comment: If it does not find the class, it seem it's missing in the classpath -- note that `TimeWindowedSerde` ships with `kafka-stream` package, not `kafka-clients`. It should be possible to add the missing jar via `$CLASSPATH` env variable.